# Nexmo C# Lib giving 'Missing username' error

Tags: vonage

I am using nexmo c# lib and using below code

```
var results = SMS.Send(new SMS.SMSRequest
                               {
                                   from = smsOptions.From,
                                   to = smsOptions.To,
                                   text = smsOptions.Text
                               });
```

added below keys in `web.config`:

```
<add key="Nexmo.UserAgent" value="myApp/1.0" />
<add key="Nexmo.Url.Rest" value="https://rest.nexmo.com" />
<add key="Nexmo.Url.Api" value="https://api.nexmo.com" />
<add key="Nexmo.api_key" value="..." />
<add key="Nexmo.api_secret" value="..." />
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using this library? https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-dotnet What version are you using?

Comment: I am exactly using github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-dotnet and version 2.1.2. Installed from nuget.

Comment: Any word @leggetter. I am still having the same issue.

Comment: @RameezRaja Missing username sounds like an API credentials issue.

I'd suggest cloning this [repo](https://github.com/sidsharma27/NexmoSMS-DotNET) to send an SMS and try to replicate the error. (I was able to successfully send SMS using multiple virtual numbers)